# While loop over a list?

Tags: python, list, while-loop, pyscripter

I have a list of numbers, and I want it so, after inputting 3 numbers, they will sum up, unless one of the numbers is 13, then the rest of the numbers will be invalid and not summed up.

So if the list were to be `[1, 13, 2]` the end sum would be 1.

```
total = 0
def lucky_sum():
    total = 0
    lucky_sum = []
    a = input("Input a number")
    b = input("Input a number")
    c = input("Input a number")
    lucky_sum.append(a)
    lucky_sum.append(b)
    lucky_sum.append(c)


while **What do I place here??** != 13:
    total += **and here**
    if i== 13:
        break
print total

lucky_sum()
```

Comment: I got a bit desperate and ended up using a for loop in front of the while loop, but that doesn't seem right either

Comment: Totally unrelated .. But you don't need to call `total = 0` prior to `lucky_sum():` if you are defining it inside..  Unless I am missing something?

Answer (score 5):

You can do it without using while loop:

```
for i in lucky_sum():
    if i == 13:
        break

    total += i
```

Edit:
As suggested in the comment, in `lucky_sum` add a return statement at the end.

Comment: Then we need put a `return lucky_sum` inside `lucky_sum()` function.

Comment: You are right. edited my answer to include the same.

Comment: Another tip is don't use `;` in Python, that's not *Pyhtonic* :P

Answer (score 3):

If you really wanted to, you could `itertools.islice` to limit to at most 3, then the two-argument version of `iter`, so your code could become:

```
from itertools import islice
print sum(islice(iter(lambda: input('Input Number: '), 13), 3))
```

To keep it simple though, use a loop in your `lucky_sum()` for 3 times unless the number entered is 13, in which case break from the loop and return the total (defaulting to zero) or just keep adding the numbers, eg:

```
def lucky_sum():
    total = 0
    for i in range(3):
        n = input('Input Number: ')
        if n == 13:
            break
        total += n
    return total

print lucky_sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using [the `sum()` built-in](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#sum) and [itertools.takewhile()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
sum(itertools.takewhile(lambda i: i != 13, lucky_sum()))
```

`sum()` takes an iterable and returns the sum, and `takewhile()` takes an iterable and returns a new iterable that gives values until the given predicate fails.

This is a more efficient way to do this, as `sum()` is extremely quick.

In full, something like this (using a [list comprehension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) to reduce repetition in the creation of the list):

```
import itertools

def lucky_sum():
    return [input("Input a number") for _ in range(3)]

total = sum(itertools.takewhile(lambda i: i != 13, lucky_sum()))

print(total)
```

Note that you could use a generator expression here instead (normal brackets instead of square brackets), and then the user would only be asked for values until they entered a `13` value, or entered 3 values, which might be desirable behaviour.

Comment: Long time no see - I still prefer my `iter` approach :p

Comment: @JonClements Indeed, I've been far too busy recently. I'd argue that `takewhile()` is more readable, personally, but pretty similar either way.